# Modifying records with helpers

Tags: meteor

Is it possible to modify a record with helpers?

Example: (_id: "CbQvD52iEFXnFML3d", name:"somename", age:"20", video:"stack.com/link.mp4").
I would like to modify all the records found before they are sent to the template.

```js
Records= new Meteor.Collection('records');

Template.test.helpers({
  record: function() {
    var info = Records.find({age:"20"});
    //modify all records found from "stack.com/link.mp4" to "stack.com/link.jpg"
    return collection with modified records
  }
});
```

```html
<template name="test">
  {{#each record}}
    {{name}}
    <img src="{{video}}">
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can apply a transform to either a particular [find](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find) or to the entire [collection](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection). In this example we'll add the transform only to the `find` used in the `record` helper:

```js
var transform = function(doc) {
  doc.video.replace(/mp4$/, 'jpg');
  return doc;
};

Template.test.helpers({
  record: function() {
    return Records.find({age: '20'}, {transform: transform});
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. I placed the code inside my helper. Is that the best place to put that code or is there a better one?

Comment: It all depends on how much you want to reuse that particular transform. If it only makes sense for that particular helper, you can place whole thing in the helper as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
var recordsArray = Records.find({age:"20"}).fetch();
recordArray.forEach( function (entry) {
 entry.video = "stack.com/link.jpg";
}

return recordsArray;
```

*Note this will not update the collections `video`. It will only change the `video` for the array;